# I installed a 64-bit OS in a 32-bit processor

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

As the title suggest, I accidentally installed 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04 in a 32-bit processor, and it is working fine for now (actually I feel my PC became more responsive). Will there be any problem in the near future though? I think my Motherboard is a 64-bit but I'm not certain, but my processor is a 32-bit. Further, I did `lscpu` and I got this:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 4
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               2659.023
BogoMIPS:              5318.04
L1d cache:             16K
L2 cache:              1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

Comment: According to the `lscpu`, your Processor is 64bit.

Comment: If everything works then you have a 64-bit CPU, then don't worry...

Comment: if you have 32 bit processor, 64bit OS will not even install

Comment: Pentium F4 or [Pentium D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_D) which are both Intel 64 – NetBurst microarchitecture (according to the CPU Family 15, Model 4 information).  The D was a dual core processor, so that's probably not yours.

Comment: Very few, if *any*, PCs (and I am using that term broadly here) sold in the last several years have CPUs that are not 64-bit capable. And as has been pointed out in answers, your CPU is 64-bit capable, as evidenced both by the output quoted as well as the fact that it works at all.

Comment: How to install ubuntu 14.04 from USB does it reqires SWAP..??

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you installed a 64-bit OS your CPU is necessarily 64-bit capable. In a 32-bit only processor the 64-bit installer not even starts.

In `lscpu` output **CPU op-mode(s):32-bit, 64-bit** means your CPU is both 32-bit and 64-bit capable. **Architecture: x86_64** is the current kernel architecture (64-bit).

You can also check 64-bit support running:

```
grep " lm " /proc/cpuinfo
```

If it outputs nothing you have a 32-bit CPU. If it outputs something like *flags : blah blah **lm** blah blah blah* your CPU supports [Long Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) (AKA 64-bit).

Comment: I did the `grep "lm" /proc/cpuinfo` and I got flags blah blah **lm** blah blah, thus satisfying your check.

Comment: There's no *blah* on my flags. Should I worry?

Comment: @ruda.almeida **blah** = "a lot of flags you don't need to worry about". **lm** is the flag that tells you have a 64-bit CPU.

Answer (score 10):

From your output it is clear that you have a 64bit CPU. The line `CPU op-mode(s):32-bit, 64-bit` means that you have a 64bit CPU.

Therefore there is no problem using a 64bit OS.

Comment: A lot of times laptops with 64-bit-capable CPUs come with a 32-bit OS anyway (since they often have too little memory for 64-bit to be very useful). This is probably the source of the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you experienced the same surprise I did a few years ago.

I accidentally put a 64-bit Ubuntu CD in my laptop and installed it, and a bit later I realised *"Wait a moment.... I thought my laptop was a 32-bit system?"*

If the 64-bit version works on your system, then that means your system is actually a 64-bit system, rather than a 32-bit one as you used to think ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is actually 64-bit processor as this line states:

Architecture: x86_64

If it has been 32-bit, you couldn't have installed a 64-bit OS in the first place. Don't worry, your PC will work just fine.

Comment: Actually **Architecture: x86_64** means there is a 64-bit kernel running. The CPU architecture is shown in line **CPU op-mode(s)**. Of course, a 64-bit kernel wouldn't run in a 32-bit only CPU, so this answer is not wrong.