# Can I install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu on my 32-bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu

I have 3 GB of RAM. The output of `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

Comment: Your machine supports 64bit. The i686 shows that you are currently running a 32bit OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Comment: technically you can hardly find a 32-bit only x86 CPU anymore. All x86 CPUs from P4 Prescott, except some old Atom CPUs, support x86_64

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You probably will be *finding* 32-bit CPU's more often now, in garage sales, recycle bins, etc... Just not buying them new

Comment: @Xen2050 I mean the ones 10 years back

Comment: You can't install a 64 bit anything on 32 bit hardware.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I installed a 64-bit OS in a 32-bit processor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313379/i-installed-a-64-bit-os-in-a-32-bit-processor)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By "32-bit machine" I understand 32-bit hardware (processor) which is not your case because `lscpu` reports that your CPU can work in 64-bit mode.

```
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
```

You have a 32-bit software (operating system) running at the moment on your PC, that's why:

```
Architecture: i686
```

But you **can** install a 64-bit operating system (you have both a compatible CPU and enough RAM for it).

Comment: Aren't ALL RAMs compatible with ALL architectures?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan yes, but at least 2 GB are recommended for 64-bit Ubuntu, while on the other hand 32-bit can run on less than 2 GB. I said "enough RAM".

Comment: Fair enough. Although 64bit OS work fairly well with < 2GB RAM too

Comment: I used to run 64-bit ubuntu live on just 2GB ram, not much "room" though (overlayfs, all files in ram). 32-bit Ubuntu actually uses less ram after booting, I *think* it's less ram-hungry, hence the higher ram requirements for 64-bit. 32-bit at least seems better for running live (more "room")

Answer (score 6):

You can install a 32 bit system on 64 bit hardware.

The converse is not true.

You cannot install a 64 bit system on 32 bit hardware.

From the output of `lscpu` you gave:

> ```
> CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
> ```

It looks like your hardware is in fact 64 bit. You can install a 64 bit system.

Comment: So the answer is definitely **YES**!

Comment: Ugh... I totally overlooked he wrote that... Thanks a lot for pointing out!